# Android How to move together imagebutton and textview?

Tags: android, button, textview

Hello i want to move ImageButton and TextView Together with animation is it possible?
I am trying to make Plane with Scoreboard so i need to use ImageButton and Textview.
Is it possible to move them together ? thank you.

```
imagebutton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img1;
TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
imagebutton1.startAnimation(animation);
textview.startAnimation(animation2);
```

Comment: put them in a layout then animate that layout.

Comment: i want to move them together like 1 object chained is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start animations together using an [Animator Set](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html).

Comment: Sir , i want to move them together like 1 object :D it should move like chained object :D

Comment: Animator set allows you to play 2 animations at the exact same time, isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, Use linear layout and put both elements in it and apply interpolator animation on that layout.